# Why are some GPX routes funny-looking?

Tags: import, gpx

When opening GPX routes I found on the Net, sometimes, they look like this in eg. RideWithGPS, but are displayed OK in Google My Maps or GPSVisualizer:

[image]

Incidently, GpsTrackEditor triggers a warning: "Adjust Time: Some points of a track do not have valid timestamps."

What is the source of the problem, and why are GMM/GPSV happy with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With each track you have a few gpx locations. Each point location should have a date and time field describing when the data was created. In my experience, these straight lines connect the last point before you turned off the GPS device and the new location where you turned it on again. It may happen in the same day, or within the same week.

Another possible reason is that, the point locations skipped one point during its course. For example, WP#6 goes somewhere else in a stream of 1 to 10. So the track connect 5, 6 and 7 with straight lines. Sometime it may happens if you decide to save your own customized WP.

Probably the most common reason is the GPS device itself. If I can understand your screenshot well, most of the anomalies happened around terrains where conventional GPS signals tend to go mad (so does its location and time). In the steam of WP, some points lost its track and fell somewhere else. Most of the time it followed the existing locations saved sometime before. When you plot all the tracks at the end it created the straight lines which I mentioned before.

Your system is happy with it because it is to connect points with lines according to the order they have been created at the field.